# Java Runtime String Parsing

Tags: java

I am using Java to execute a Python command, i.e.

```
ctool run <cluster_name> <nodes> <command>
```

So basically this runs the `<command>` in given nodes of the cluster. For example:

```
ctool run my_cluster all 'rm -rf /home/tester/folder'
```

This runs 'rm -rf /home/tester/folder' on 'all' the nodes of 'my_cluster' which runs perfectly fine from the terminal but when I am running this from java runtime as a string, it is taking any option like `-p`, `-r`, etc. in the   `<command>` as ctool option and throwing usage error.

I am assuming it has something to do with how is string parsing the command. Is there a way I can fix this issue?

Comment: Post the code so we can see the issue if there is one.

Comment: Show the java code you're using to run the command...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("rm","-rf","/home/tester/folder").start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String out;
while ((out = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(out);
}
```